# How to split a string using regex when the delimiter in the front while keeping the delimiter?

Tags: regex, split

I have the following string that I am trying to split:

```
"03/04/1987", "Joseph", "Sam", "F", "12/09/1976", "Saram", "Mary", "M","08/10/1969", "Shik", "Shaary", "F"
```

I need to split this string into multiple string using a regex. The result should look like this:

```
"03/04/1987", "Joseph", "Sam", "F"
"12/09/1976", "Saram", "Mary", "M"
"08/10/1969", "Shik", "Shaary", "F"
```

Thank you for your help

---

I found the answer (?=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}). Thank you.

Comment: In this a java question?

Comment: (?<=\d{2}/\d{2}/\d  I tried this. But not exactly what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to provide a more complete solution if you indicated what flavor of regex you are using.  However, you could split on a comma that is followed by zeri or more spaces and qualified with a positive lookahead for the date string.  Using the lookahead ensures that the quoted date string itself will not be removed.

```
,\s*(?="\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}")
```

In .NET you might use:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @",\s*(?=""\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"")", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\"[FM]\",) ");
```

It uses a positive look-behind to assert, but not capture, that the characters preceding the space are either `"F",` or `"M",`.

Comment: The delimeter is \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}.  Sometimes records may not have F or M. But definitely starts with the date.

Answer (score 0):

perfomr a split using this patter `,\s*(?=(([^"]*"){8})*$)` or replace with `\n` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vG7bM8)